# Nested wIth existing objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm attempting to build a form which allows a user to select multiple Labels when creating a new Item, without allowing the user to create new Labels.

Here's how my models are set up:

```
Item
has_many :item_labels
has_many :labels, :through => :item_labels

ItemLabel
belongs_to :item
belongs_to :label

Label
has_many :item_labels
has_many :items, :through => :item_labels
```

Any ideas how I could create this sort of relationship within a form without allowing the user to create new labels? (Label creation is only done by the admin.)

Specifically, how should I set up the form in the view, and are there any changes I should make to my models? (`accepts_nested_parameters` or other directives)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you'll need `accepts_nested_attributes` for this. I haven't tried all this out, so YMMV :)

Here's how you might set up a new item in your controller. I'm setting a `@labels` instance variable, too, since I'll use that in a `collection_select` in the view:

```
# items_controller.rb
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @items = Item.all
  end

  def new
    @item = Item.new
    @labels = Label.all
  end

  def create
    @item = Item.new(params[:item])

    if @item.save
      flash[:info] = 'Item successfully created.'
      redirect_to items_path
    else
      @labels = Label.all
      render :new
    end
  end
end
```

Assuming your `Label` model has a `name` attribute, your form could look like this:

```
# new.html.erb
<%= form_form @item do |f| %>
  <!-- Other item fields go here -->

  <%= f.label :label_ids %>
  <%= f.collection_select :label_ids, @labels, :id, :name, {}, multiple: true %>

  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

You can read some more about [collection_select](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select) to learn a bit more about that.

Comment: @Rob glad to hear it!

Answer (score 1):

Well, what part are you stuck on?

For the UI side, you might consider the chosen-rails gem:

https://github.com/tsechingho/chosen-rails

It lets users just start typing the name of an item and it helps them auto-complete it, similar to what happens when you select recipients for a message in Facebook.  I think you should be able to use it to let the user select multiple labels.

Comment: I know if I'm creating new objects I would do something like f.fields_for :labels do... Then edit the model to accept_nested_attributes. Is it done similarly with existing objects? I can't seem to find this anywhere on google